# upload file using flask to amazon s3

Tags: python, file-upload, amazon-s3, flask

This is the code that handles the uploading request:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request
        data_file = request.files.get('file')
        file_name = data_file.filename
        conn = S3Connection(settings.ACCESS_KEY, settings.SECRET_KEY)
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.BUCKET_NAME)
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = 'file_test.jpg'
        # k.set_contents_from_file(data_file)
        k.set_contents_from_string(data_file.readlines())

        # return jsonify(name=file_name)
        return jsonify(name=file_name)
```

I've tried 3 options:

```
k.set_contents_from_string(data_file.readlines())
k.set_contents_from_file(data_file)
k.set_contents_from_stream(data_file.readlines())
```

So what is the right way to upload files to amazon s3?

Comment: can you include the error you get? Btw try using `set_contents_from_string(data_file.read())`.

Comment: i put it in an answer, would you please accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code in the following line:

```
k.set_contents_from_string(data_file.readlines())
```

you're sending a `list` of strings (terminated by newlines!) to Amazon instead of the file content as is.

You need to pass a single `str` object with the file contents:

```
set_contents_from_string(data_file.read())
```

Comment: I'm encountering this exact same issue however following your suggestion gives me an error: `'FileField' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @haye321 what is `FileField`? what are you using? What framework? Django? Flask+WTForms? Are you `POST`ing the form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [fully-functioning example](https://github.com/sasaporta/s3multifile) of how to upload multiple files to Amazon S3 using an HTML file input tag, Python, Flask and Boto.'

The main keys to making this work are Flask's `request.files.getlist` and Boto's `set_contents_from_string`.

Some tips:

- Be sure to set S3 bucket permissions and IAM user permissions, or the upload will fail. The details are in the readme.
- Don't forget to include *enctype="multipart/form-data"* in your HTML form tag.
- Don't forget to include the attribute *multiple* in your HTML input tag.
- Don't forget to store the AWS user's credentials in environment variables as shown in the readme. Make sure these environment variables are available in the session where Python is running.